# Error: Unable to initialize main class AirMail Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Authenticator

Tags: java, email, jar, awt, jakarta-mail

I am creating a Java Application with Swing , AWT and Mail API  whose name is   **AirMail.**
Which Sends Email with a featuer of attaching file and this email service is provided by Gmail (Google).

I have created its jar file on command line by **jar -cvmf manifest.mf AirMail.jar** command .
**So , I'm getting an error when I, launch jar file.**
Error :

`Unable to initialize main class AirMail Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Authenticator`

As, above error says  NoClassDefFoundError  in javax/mail/Authenticator .
I check out , javax/mail/Authenticator class is present or not  in the Mail API.
and , Yes It  is Present.

Usually, we need to provide Main-Class value in  **manifest.mf** file and I have checked my **Manifest.mf** file and added its Main-Class value along  with this   Ive already left a blank line at the end of **Manifest.mf** file.

**Content of Manifest.mf file**

- Manifest-Version: 1.0
- Created-By: 11.0.7 (Oracle Corporation)
- Main-Class: AirMail

I'm Providing a link to my AirMail.java code.

https://github.com/thesumitsuryawanshi/Air-Mail/blob/master/AirMail.java

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 "64-bit"

**Any Help !!
or
Extra Knowledge about my question would be appreciated.!!
Thank you !!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFIK javax.mail package is not part of Java 11. you need to add this as a dependency to your project.

for maven this could work

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/javax.mail -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Perfect !!   I think ,  without your reply I wouldn't have executed my program . Thank you So much Brother !!    :)        can I have your Whats-app or telegram no  , So we could Grow with helping each other !        :)